# How to execute VBA function from MS Access Form?

Tags: ms-access

I have Access Form with some Text fields and one Button.
Is there any posibility to execute VBA function with passed parameters from Access Form: on button Click? I know that I can exectute Macro but this doesnt resolve my problem. I need to execute VBA.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the VBA function/sub in a module as public you can call the function/sub in the click event on the form.

Comment: But how to do that? I have module: AccessHelper and public function named: InertTest(Foo As String)
On OnClick event im tying to insert: "AccessHelper.InsertTest([TextField])" but this doesnt work for me :(

Comment: Ok, it works! I need to go to VBA Editor and select Microsoft Office Access Class Objects node instead of writing function name in Button OnClick property page.